# How to find date of Second Sunday of March in Hive for any year?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to retrieve the date of every second sunday of March for any given year in Hive.

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need a database for this?

Answer (score 1):

select date_add("1901-03-01",cast(7-date_format("1901-03-01",'u') as int)+7);

Comment: Wow.. I did not know about the number-date_format. There is no documentation on this.. How did you find it out?  :)

Comment: @SagarMorakhia Look at the docs https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF, find unix_timestamp, there is a link to the SimpleDateFormat class java docs. SimpleDateFormat is what Hive uses

Comment: Yeah.. That I know that Hive uses Simple Date Format. I was not aware of 2-date_format, 7-date_format, etc functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. In the below query, All you need to do is change your year value and you will get your output.

```
SELECT  if(cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-03-14','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS int) ==7, date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-03-15','yyyy-MM-dd')), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-03-15','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS int)), date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-03-14','yyyy-MM-dd')),cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2019-03-14','yyyy-MM-dd'), 'u') AS int)));
```

If it works for you, do not forget to thumbs up on the answer. :)
Spent half n hour to get to this, :)